# CSS styling first option in Select drop down

Tags: css, forms

I have had a look at a few solutions to this problem on stack overflow, but all the jsfiddles etc don't seem to have solved the problem (I may be wrong though).

I am trying to style a contact form similar (but maybe simpler) to this: http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/NaturalLanguageForm/

My form reads something like:

"Hi there, I want to ask you about [select drop down list]."

And then the user goes through entering and selecting options to complete the form.

However the issue I am having is how to style the first option or placeholder for the select list.  I am using Wordpress Contact Form 7, so there isn't a lot of flexibility jQuery wise.  I am looking for a simple CSS solution to the problem.  There is not a placeholder option for select menu when using Contact Form 7.

1. Is there a way I can target the first option and make it appear grey rather than black.  This is before it has been triggered, and then to not display that first option when the actual list is displayed?
2. Alternatively, is there a way via CSS to add placeholder option before the list? And then to style this instead?

The list is displayed like this:

```
<select name="subject" id="id_subject">
    <option value="How can I help?">How can I help?</option>
    <option value="Lets work together!">Lets work together!</option>
    <option value="I have a question!">I have a question!</option>
    <option value="I love your work!">I love your work!</option>
</select>
```

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

you can try

`li:first-of-type{
    // some style...
}`

to target the first option and style it

Comment: ah sorry I should have said that its an <option> list and not a <li> list.

Comment: well.. you can not control the style of <option>, it is always rendered by native, I thought you can use a JavaScript Widgets to do that, if you want more control

Comment: I adjusted the balance for you. Thank you for your suggestion regardless

Comment: That's very kind of you to do that

Answer (score 0):

1. There is a way, *but you get different results in different browsers*. You can use the `first-child` pseudo element or add class to the option like below.

```css
option {
  color: #000;
}
option:first-child, option.first {
  color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<select>
  <option class="first">One</option>
  <option>Two</option>
  <option>Three</option>
</select>
```

2. Not with just CSS. One thing I have seen that works with different results in different browsers is to set `display:none` on the first element. I'm not a huge fan of this choice or using placeholders in general for select tags until we get full support. Another thing to think about is setting the `disabled` attribute on your first option tag.

**tl;dr Styling select tags kind of stinks right now and will stink for a while to come. Everything feels like a hack.**

If you want to do advance things with a select tag, I would choose a JavaScript library. You may want to try [Select2](https://select2.github.io/), [Chosen](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/) or [Selectize.js](http://brianreavis.github.io/selectize.js/)

Comment: this doesn't work for me. When I run the code snippet, the colour of all drop down options is the same.  I have added some jQuery to my site that adds a class to every first option.  And even when I target it directly by name '.first' it still doesn't change colour.

Comment: It's very browser dependent. What browser are you using?

Comment: I tried it on both mac versions of safari and chrome.

Comment: This is what I see in Chrome on Windows. Is this not what you were expecting? http://i.imgur.com/z20K4zg.png Going back to my thoughts, I would still use a select tag library replacement instead of styling the select tag and fighting through issues like you're encountering now.

Answer (score 0):

If somebody is looking for the same effect (first option in one style, the rest in another), I solved this problem overlaying the select with an element that look exactly the same (matching css dimensions) with

```
position: absolute
pointer-events: none
```

to click the select throught the overlay.

This also mean the first option is not necessary.
And this works whatever the browser